# puts(), gets(), getchar(), putchar() function simultaneously use in the program

Tags: c, getchar, gets, puts, putchar

I have a confusion related to using `puts()`, `gets()`, `putchar()` and `getchar()` simultaneously use in the code.

When I have run the below code, it is doing all steps:
taking the input, printing the output, again taking the input, printing the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch[34];
    gets(ch);
    puts(ch);

    char g;
    g = getchar();
    putchar(g);
}
```

Output:

```
Priyanka
Priyanka
J
J
```

But, when I am using this code:
It is only doing two steps:
taking the input, printing the input, then one line space. I am not getting why it behaves like this.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char g;
    g = getchar();
    putchar(g);   
 
    char ch[34];
    gets(ch);
    puts(ch);
    getch();
}
```

Output:

```
P
P
```

Comment: `gets()` is deprecated from both C and C++ standards. It's very dangerous to use too.

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is too dangerous to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) for a detailed discussion of why you should never, ever use `gets()` and about alternatives.

Comment: Note that `getch()` used in the last example is not a standard C function.

Comment: The sequence of operations in the second example is: you type "P" and hit return (and the letter and newline displayed by the terminal driver); the `getchar()` returns the letter 'P'; the `putchar()` outputs the 'P', but it doesn't appear yet; the `gets()` reads the newline and returns an empty string; the `puts()` outputs the empty string and a newline, also forcing the 'P' to be displayed.  If you typed "Priyanka" instead of just "P", you'd get a similar result with "Priyanka" appearing twice.  If you used `putchar('X')` after `putchar(g);` and typed "Priyanka", you'd see "PXriyanka".

Comment: Note that production code would need to check that the input operations succeeded, and you'd also need to use `int g` instead of `char g` because `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char` (and the difference does matter in some circumstances).

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in the code and the input mechanisms are more complex than you infer:

- you should not read input with `gets()`: this function cannot be used safely because it does not receive information about the destination array size so any sufficiently long input line will cause a buffer overflow. It has been removed from the C Standard. You should use `fgets()` instead and deal with the newline at the end of the buffer.
- `g` should have type `int` to accommodate for all the values returned by `getc()`, namely all values of type `unsigned char` (in most current systems `0` to `255`) and the special negative value `EOF` (usually -1).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch[34];
    if (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, stdin))
        fputs(ch, stdout);

    int g = getchar();
    if (g != EOF)
        putchar(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Priyanka
Priyanka
J
J
```

Regarding the behavior of the console in response to your program's input requests, it is implementation defined but usually involves 2 layers of buffering:

- the `FILE` stream package implements a buffering scheme where data is read from or written to the system in chunks. This buffering can be controlled with `setvbuf()`. 3 settings are available: no buffering (which is the default for `stderr`), line buffered (usually the default for `stdin` and `stdout` when attached to a character device) and fully buffered with a customisable chunk size (common sizes are 512 and 4096).
- when you call `getchar()` or more generally `getc(stream)`, if a byte is available in the stream's buffer, it is returned and the stream position is incremented, otherwise a request is made to the system to fill the buffer.
- if the stream is attached to a file, filling the buffer performs a `read` system call or equivalent, which succeeds unless at the end of file or upon a read error.
- if the stream is attached to a character device, such as a terminal or a virtual tty like a terminal window on the graphics display, another layer of buffering gets involved where the device driver reads input from the input device and handles some keys in a special way such as <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to erase the previous character, cursor movement keys to move inside the input line, <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> (unix) or <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> (windows) to signal the end of file. This layer of buffering can be controlled via the `tcsetattr()` system call or other system specific APIs. Interactive applications such as text editors typically disable this and retrieve raw input directly from the input device.
- the keys typed by the user are handled by the terminal to form an input line, send back to the C stream API when the user types <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which is translated as a system specific end of line sequence), the stream functions perform another set of transformations (ie: converting `CR`/`LF` to `'\n'` on legacy systems) and the line of bytes is stored in the stream buffer. When `getc()` finally gets a chance to return the first available byte, the full line has already been typed and entered by the user and is pending in the stream or the device buffers.

In both programs, `getchar()` does not return the next byte read from `stdin` until a full line has been read from the terminal and stored in the stream buffer. In the first program, the rest of this line is ignored as the program exits, but in the second program, the rest of this line is available for the subsequent `gets()` to read. If you typed <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the line read is `J\n` and `getchar()` returns the `'J'`, leaving the newline [ending in the input stream, then `gets()` will read the newline and return an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Between the lines of the statements `putchar()` and ***`gets()`* *that I don't recommend using***, discarding the input stream until EOF or till a newline occurs solves the problem:

```
.
.
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
  ;
.
.
```

I would recommend using [`fgets(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) which is quite safer to use, for example:

```
char str[1024];
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) {
  // Some problem, handle the error...
}

// or, Input is okay...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a problem here.  You use a function in your second sample code that is not part of the stdio package.

You call `getch()`  which is not a stdio function.  It is part of the ncurses library, and, if you don't specify on compilation that you will use it, then you cannot get an executable program.  So this make me thing you are not telling all the truth.

Just taking the function `getch()` of of the program you get the full line

```
Priyanka
```

output, and the program terminated.  I guess you used `getch()` to stop the output until you press a character.  But as curses library requires you to call `initscr()` before calling any other curses library function, it is not correctly initialized, and the output you get can be wrong due to this.

I'll not repeat what others have already told you about the use of `gets()`, it is still in the standard library, and knowing what you do, you can still use it in properly controlled environments.  Despite of that, the recommendation others have given to you is not applicable here, as you have not overflowed the short buffer you have used (of only 34 chars, too short, too easy to hang your program or to crash it)

The functions from stdio use a buffer, and the unix tty driver is also interferring here.  Your terminal will not make available any character you input to the program until you press the `<ENTER>` key, then all those characters are read by the program into a buffer.  They are consumed from the buffer, until it is empty, so it doesn't matter if you read them one by one (with `fgetch()`, or all at once (with `fgets()` ---i'll use this, more secure, function, from this point on)  Everything just happens once you press the `<ENTER>` key.

`fgetch()` only takes one character, so if more than one are available, only one character is taken from the buffer, and the rest wait their turn.  But `fgets()` reads all (and fills the buffer) until a `\n` is read (this is why `gets()` is so dangerous, because it doesn't know the size of your buffer /it doesn't have a parameter indicating the size of the buffer, as `fgets()` has/  and cannot control the read to stop before overflowing it)

So, in your case, as you press a series of characters, then hit return, the first sample reads the full string, and then the second `getchar()` takes the first of the second line (but you need to input two complete lines at that point)  The second sample read the first char when you called `getchar()`, and the rest of the line when you called `gets()`.

To read one character at a time, without waiting for a full line to be input, the terminal driver has to be programmed to read characters in raw mode.  Cookied mode (the default) is used by unix to read complete lines, this allows you to edit, erase characters on the line, and only input it when you are ready and hit the `<ENTER>` key.

If you are interested in reading chars one by one from the terminal, read the manual page `termios(4)` which explains the interface and iocontrols to the `tty` device.  The curses library does the necessary housekeeping to put the terminal in raw mode to allow programs like `vi(1)` to read the input char by char, but you need then not to use stdio directly, as its buffering system will eat the characters you try to get to eat with curses.